# Rails: Embed an image in submit button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

With `link_to`, we can embed content like this:

```
<%= link_to '#' do &>
  <img>
```

By doing so, we could change a text link into other.

However, When using forms, the button is achieve in html using `<input>`, and I'm unable to replace it like `link_to`. How can I do something like:

```
<%= f.submit "#" do %>
  <img>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **[`image_submit tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/image_submit_tag)** instead of `f.submit`

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= image_submit_tag("/images/submit.png") %>
```

or HTML

```
<input alt="Submit" src="/images/submit.png" type="image" />
```